# Changing ASCII values in a list

Tags: python

I'm working on taking a string such as "HELLO WORLD" and converting it to ASCII using ord().
With this code:

```
word="HELLO WORLD"
word2=[ord(c) for c in word]
print(word2)
```

The output for word2 is `[72, 69, 76, 76, 79, 32, 87, 79, 82, 76, 68]` which is good but I can't figure out how update each value. I want to be able to change each value by a certain integer such as three. In the case of three the output I want is `[75, 72, 79, 79, 82, 32, 90, 82, 85, 79, 71]` which is "JHOOR ZRUOG" but I can't seem to figure out how to properly update the list. Any advice? I'm still pretty new to python.

Comment: 75 is not `J`, it is `K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close to discovering the solution yourself -- you just need to use list comprehensions again, but slightly differently

```
word="HELLO WORLD"
word2=[ord(c) for c in word]
print(word2)

shifted_by_3 = [num + 3 for num in word2]
print(shifted_by_3)

word3 = [chr(num) for num in shifted_by_3]
print word3
```

This'll get you pretty close to what you want -- you'll print out the list of shifted numbers, then a list of their ASCII equivalents. Later, you might want to look into using modulus or something so that if you shift a letter beyond the letter 'Z', you wrap it back around to the start of the alphabet.

To combine `word3` into a string again, you can use `str.join`:

```
print(''.join(word3))
```

This'll take everything in `word3`, and combine them into a single string, separating each element in the list by `''` -- the empty string. Try playing around with this feature -- it's really useful. For example, what happens if you do the following?

```
print('--'.join(word3))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That helps a lot. Now I can finish my python assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line

```
word2=[ord(c) for c in word]
```

goes through every letter in word, and creates a new list by converting them to their integer value by using `ord(c)`

Since all you want to do is increment that integer value by a constant number(for example, 3), you can do that by modifying the line in this way:

```
word2=[ord(c)+3 for c in word]
```